# Mongodb 3.2 aggregation $lookup for nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: memberships and categories.
In the categories I have stored array of objects called ageGroups.

```
memberships : [{
   _id: ObjectId,
   ageCategory: ObjectId,
   ageGroup: ObjectId
}]

categories: {
   _id: ObjectId,
   ageGroups: [{
       _id: ObjectId,
       name: String
       }, {
       _id: ObjectId,
       name: String
       }, {
       _id: ObjectId,
       name: String
   }]
}
```

There are `ageCategory` and `ageGroup` properties in memberships collection.
Now i need to aggregate these two and get result like this

```
[{
  id: 'membership id here',
  ageGroup: 'Age Group name here'
},{
  id: '2 membership id here',
  ageGroup: '2 membership age Group name here'
}]
```

So I tried

```
db.memberships.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'categories', localField: 'ageCategory', foreignField: '_id', as: 'ageCategory'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$ageCategory'
    },
    {
        $project: {
          'group': {
             $filter: { 
                  input : '$ageCategory.ageGroups', 
                  as    : 'group',
                  cond : 'group._id' == '$_id'
             }
           }
        }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$group'
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'group' : '$group.name'
        }
    }
]);
```

This query return empty result. As much as I understand, problem in filter condition

`$filter: { 
    input : '$ageCategory.ageGroups', 
    as    : 'group',
    cond : 'group._id' == '$_id'
}` 
when I tried to set `true` in `cond`, it pushed new document to result, for each group, even if ageGroup not that, which is assigned to membership. Thanks for help!

**UPD**
I found solution,

```
{
    $project: {
        'group': {
             $filter: { 
                  input : '$ageCategory.ageGroups', 
                  as    : 'group',
                  cond : { $eq:['$$group._id', '$ageGroup']}
             }
         }
     }
 },
```

I have added double dollar sign with $eq operator and problem has been solved. Now I search better solution and I would like have a query which get similar result

```
{ 
    "_id" : // member id, 
    "group" : "1-3 members"
}
{ 
    "_id" : //member id, 
    "group" : "17-19 members"
}
```

without storing ageCategory in memberships table, only with ageGroup id.

Comment: @user3100115 Hi, thanks for reply, I edited the question.

Comment: Of course you can't use `==` in MongoDB queries you have to use the `$eq` operator.